# conditional where Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query

```
select idpays,idannonce,idville 
from annonces
```

and i need to make a conditional where, where `idpays=1` don't show `idville` `null` else for other `idpays` show `idville` `null`

How can i do this please?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what, exactly, should be displayed when idpays=1, but here's a basis for what you've asked - you can do this with a case in the SELECT which sounds more like the problem you've described rather than a where clause:

```
select idpays,idannounce, 
       case when idpays=1 then idville 
       else null end
  from unknowntable
```

**EDIT based on OP comments- must admit I'm not sure I understand the OP's requirements exactly at this point:**

```
select 
  from table
 where (idpays<>1) or
       (idpays=1 and idville not null)
```

Comment: I have 10 annonces with Idpays=1: 5 idville nul and 5 not null, 10 annones with idpays!=1 , i need to get the 10 annonces with idpays!=1 and the 5 with idpays 5 and idville not null

Comment: Edited as best I've interpreted your requirements. Are you saying you are looking for records with idpays=5?

Answer (score 3):

You may looking for this

```
WHERE ( idpays = 1 AND idville NOT NULL) OR idpays > 1
```

Comment: I think that's correct, but your answer is assuming idpays are all positive numbers; if that's not the case, then idpays<>1 would be the correct secondary condition.

Answer (score 1):

If your `idpays` column contain `NULL` value:

```
select idpays,idannonce,idville 
from annonces
where (idpays = 1 AND idville IS NOT NULL) OR (ISNULL(idpays, 0) <> 1)
```

If you are looking for NOT NULL values for idpays = 1 and **only** NULL values for idpays <> 1.

```
select idpays,idannonce,idville 
from annonces
where (idpays = 1 AND idville IS NOT NULL) OR (ISNULL(idpays, 0) <> 1 AND idville IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CASE function. I don't think you need the ELSE statement at all:

```
SELECT idpays, iddonance,
CASE WHEN idpays = 1 THEN idville END AS idville
FROM annonces
```